# Handling form post in Umbraco 11

Tags: umbraco

I'm new to umbraco (v11) and am struggling with something that Im sure can be answered fairly quickly.

I need to create a page which will contain a single text box and a button.

When the page renders we set some values in the view model.

When the button is clicked the form will be posted back to the server and the data validated.
If the data is not valid (either formatted incorrectly/not the expected value) then we set modelstate errors and re-render the page.

If the value is as expected then we redirect to another page.

This is my view Model

```cs
public class ExampleViewModel : PublishedContentWrapped
{
    public ExampleViewModel (IPublishedContent content, IPublishedValueFallback publishedValueFallback) : base(content, publishedValueFallback)
    { }
    
    public string MessageSent { get; set; }
    
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller (Snipped for brevity)

```cs
public class ExampleController : RenderController
    {
        private readonly IVariationContextAccessor _variationContextAccessor;
        private readonly ServiceContext _context;
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        
        public ExampleController(
            ILogger<ExampleController> logger,
            ICompositeViewEngine compositeViewEngine,
            IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor,
            IVariationContextAccessor variationContextAccessor,
            ServiceContext context,
            IMediator mediator)
            : base(logger, compositeViewEngine, umbracoContextAccessor)
        {
            _variationContextAccessor = variationContextAccessor;
            _context = context;
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public override IActionResult Index()
        {
            var exampleViewModel = new ExampleViewModel(CurrentPage, new PublishedValueFallback(_context, _variationContextAccessor))
            {
                MessageSentVia = mfaResponse.SendMethod,
                MaskedPhoneNumber = mfaResponse.MaskedContact
            };

            return CurrentTemplate(exampleViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ExampleViewModel viewModel) 
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("exampleViewModel", "One or more of the given answers was not in the expected format.");

                return CurrentTemplate(CurrentPage);
            }

            if (viewModel.Code == "1234")
            {
                return Redirect("/NextPage/");
            }

            // Answer is incorrect 

            ModelState.AddModelError("exampleViewModel", validationResponse.ErrorMessage);

           return CurrentTemplate(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

Finally the view is

```html
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels;
@inherits Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Views.UmbracoViewPage<TP.Landing.Web.UI.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels;
@{
    Layout = "Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>@Model.Value("pageTitle")</h1>

@Model.Value("pageContent")

<p>We have sent you a code via @Model.MessageSentVia to the contact @Model.MaskedPhoneNumber</p>

<div class="container justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3">

    <form action="@Url.Action("")" method="POST" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=> Model.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=> Model.MessageSent)

        @Html.ValidationSummary("exampleViewModel", true, "", new {@class = "alert alert-danger"})

        <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center text-uppercase fw-bolder w-100" placeholder="Confirmation Code" asp-for="Code" maxlength="5" size="5" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-3">Submit</button>

    </form>

</div>
```

The problem is that when I submit the form I get an exception
`ModelBindingException: Cannot bind source content type Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels.Example to model type TP.Landing.Web.UI.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel. The source is a ModelsBuilder type, but the view model is not. The application is in an unstable state and should be restarted.`

I kind of understand what the problem is here as the ExampleViewModel is a wrapper around an Umbraco published model and on the post it wont have any of the umbraco bits - just my extras from the wrapper.

Could someone clarify what the issue is here and how I resolve this?

If I move the post into a surface controller how do we drop them back on the form with the validation messages when they enter an incorrect value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is a [SurfaceController](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/surface-controllers). This controller is able to handle the postback, but leave the routing to Umbraco (as this is directed by the content).

What you are using is a RenderController. The rendercontroller is to change the serving behaviour of a particular document type. It is not build to intercept HTTP posts.